# What should I do if I was put in a reserved list for PhD study?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Today I received the result of a PhD program, and they said, "I regret to inform you that the Committee is not able to recommend your admission to the program at this time. However, please note that your name is currently on a reserve list. If a place becomes available, we will let you know immediately".
All I can think right now is just waiting and hoping. However, any advice on what I should do now? Should I ask them how my rank on the reserved list is?

Comment: Time to start implementing your plan B.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do anything besides perhaps a polite brief "thank you".

You can probably assume you will not be admitted off the waiting list and instead wait to hear back from your other options (or quickly make some other options, including options besides PhD programs, if you have none).

If they have a spot open up, they'll let you know (as their email said).

Answer (score 1):

Thank them for letting you know.